# Responsividade HTML/CSS

Tags: html

Estou ajustando um código, e não consigo de forma alguma, fazer com que as setinhas de prev e next no carrosel, apareçam no mobile! Já ajustei pelas media queries, mas nada resolve!

O codigo é extenso pra colocar aqui, então, quem puder dar uma olhadinha, ele está publicado aqui: 
www.extudando.esy.es/hotsite

e pode baixar os arquivos aqui:
www.extudando.esy.es/hotsite/hotsite1.zip

Comment: Primeiro de tudo. Não dá pra saber se é problemas com Media Query. Pode ser uma propriedade que se aplica na função JS que cria o Carrossel. Qual biblioteca você está usando para criar o carrossel?

Comment: Pelo que vi ele está escondendo as setas com CSS Inline. Então provavelmente quem está fazendo isso é o próprio script da biblioteca. Por isso deve ter uma propriedade que dê para escolher isso. Se você colocar uma classe `.slick-slider .slick-arrow{
display: block!important;
}` funcionaria, mas não é uma boa prática.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda assim não funcionou =/

Comment: Isso provavelmente ocorre pq a interação em mobile é arrastando com o dedo e não clicando. No plugin que vc usou provavelmente em uma opção para habilitar as setas em telas pequena. Da uma olhada na documentação do plugin e veja o Script de ativação que lá deve ter a opção de ativar as setas.

Answer (score 0):

O responsável por isso é a propriedade `arrows`, deve ser `true` quando for de determinado tamanho. Você especifica.

```
$('.responsive').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 320,
        settings: {
            arrows: true
        }
    }]
});
```